# Can you pass Airflow templated variables with their actual type into Operators?

Tags: python, airflow, jinja2

I know that you can pass templated variables as string into operators, but I'd like to pass them around as their actual type.
For example, if I have (trivial function just to illustrate my point)

```
def get_day(datetime_object):
    return datetime_object.day
```

And a DAG with task

```
py_op=PythonOperator(
   task_id='foo', 
   python_callable=get_day, 
   op_args=[
     {{ ts }}
   ]
)
```

I get an error saying that `{{ ts }}` is undefined, but if I pass it wrapped in a string like `"{{ ts }}"` then the value is passed without errors, however, it's passed as a string, so `get_day` would error because strings have no `day` property, which would mean I'd have to add another step in `get_day` to parse the string as a `datetime` object, and that's of course a bit silly if I already have an original `datetime` object.

Answer (score 1):

`{{ xx }}` is the Jinja template that should be used within string like `'echo "{{ xx }}"'` where an operator accepts templated string.

Though, you are using Python function which already has access to all [macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.5/macros.html).

```
def get_day(**kwargs):
    str_ts = kwargs['ts'] # or 'ds' if you only need the day
    # you still need to parse this str_ts with datetime though, ts macro return in string
    ...

PythonOperator(
   task_id='foo', 
   python_callable=get_day, 
   # no need to pass op_args
)
```